# Three js Add plane to the scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to add  a plane to the scene but if I check children's scene nothing is added.

```
var plane = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 2000, 2000, 8, 8 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00, opacity: 0.25 } ) );
plane.visible = true;
this.scene.add( plane );
```

Answer (score 23):

try this:

```
var geo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(2000, 2000, 8, 8);
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);

scene.add(plane);
```

if you want to use the plane as a floor, you have to rotate it.

```
plane.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2);
```